# Sorted navigation menu with Jekyll and Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm constructing a static site (no blog) with Jekyll/Liquid. I want it to have an auto-generated navigation menu that lists all existing pages and highlight the current page. The items should be added to the menu in a particular order. Therefore, I define a `weight` property in the pages' YAML:

```
---
layout : default
title  : Some title
weight : 5
---
```

The navigation menu is constructed as follows:

```
<ul>
  {% for p in site.pages | sort:weight %}
    <li>
      <a {% if p.url == page.url %}class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ p.url }}">
        {{ p.title }}
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This creates links to all existing pages, but they're unsorted, the `sort` filter seems to be ignored. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: I just found out: The `sort` *does* something. If a site does not provide a `weight`, it gets written last. But if it does provide one, it is still not ordered according to it, but according to the file name.

Comment: I believe that the sort filter might only work with output markup (things wrapped in {{ }}, not {% %}).  So, it might not work with as a filter on the for loop.  My comment is based on this page: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers and that it says the filters are for output markup.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Since Jekyll 2.2.0 you can sort an array of objects by any object property. You can now do :

```
{% assign pages = site.pages | sort:"weight"  %}
<ul>
  {% for p in pages %}
    <li>
      <a {% if p.url == page.url %}class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ p.url }}">
        {{ p.title }}
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And save a lot of build time compared to @kikito solution.

**edit**: 
You **MUST** assign your sorting property as an integer `weight: 10` and not as a string `weight: "10"`.

Assigning sorting properties as string will ends up in a a string sort like "1, 10, 11, 2, 20, ..."

Comment: does not work for me (Jekyll 2.4.0). I defined the weight property in the pages as said above, but the sort seems to ignore it.

Comment: @eyetea you are right. We need to make an assignment first. I've editer my code and it works on Jekyll 2.4.0. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also edited the code and removed the second sort filter, since it looks like it's not needed anymore.

Comment: You're right. I've edited it myself because your suggested edit was rejected by 3 users ???

Comment: strange, I just deleted the "| sort: weight"... Why would it be rejected? Anyway, problem solved.

Comment: I get an error in 2.4.0: `Error: comparison of Jekyll::Page with Jekyll::Page failed`  .... ?

Comment: mh turns out you can't use decimal numbers like `2.1` as weight... :) have to put them into quotes. Thanks though

Answer (score 36):

Your only option seems to be using a double loop.

```
<ul>
{% for weight in (1..10) %}
  {% for p in site.pages %}
    {% if p.weight == weight %}
      <li>
        <a {% if p.url == page.url %}class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ p.url }}">
          {{ p.title }}
        </a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Ugly as it is, it should work. If you also have pages without a weight, you will have to include an additional internal loop just doing `{% unless p.weight %}` before/after the current internal one.

Comment: lol. I guess you can trim that down by compressing everything into one single line of code if that is a concern. Unfortunately liquid doesn't have a `{%-` `%}` prefix to collapse empty lines like erb.

Comment: Just an addition: Replacing (1..10) with (1..site.pages.size) makes this loop as short as possible, and will work regardless of how many pages you have. Thanks for a stupid yet highly clever hack :)

Comment: @MarkusAmaltheaMagnuson the `(1..10)` on this code represent possible weights. It could be replaced by `(1..MAX_WEIGHT)` to make it a bit more clear (and have MAX_WEIGHT defined somewhere else, like in a constants file).

Comment: This worked for me, except that the "active" class needed to go on the <li> instead of the <a>

Comment: This is one of the best things about Jekyll/static-generation - "ugly" as it may be, it only runs once which doesn't affect the user experience or server load. **Nice solution!**

Answer (score 29):

Below solution works on Github (doesn't require a plugin):

```
{% assign sorted_pages = site.pages | sort:"name" %}
{% for node in sorted_pages %}
  <li><a href="{{node.url}}">{{node.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Above snippet sorts pages by file name (`name` attribute on Page object is derived from file name). I renamed files to match my desired order: `00-index.md`, `01-about.md` – and presto! Pages are ordered.

One gotcha is that those number prefixes end up in the URLs, which looks awkward for most pages and is a real problem in with 00-index.html. Permalilnks to the rescue:

```
---
layout: default
title: News
permalink: "index.html"
---
```

P.S. I wanted to be clever and add custom attributes just for sorting. Unfortunately custom attributes are not accessible as methods on Page class and thus can't be used for sorting:

```
{% assign sorted_pages = site.pages | sort:"weight" %} #bummer
```

Comment: You good sir deserve a medal. I was just about to resort to generating my site locally and pushing the static HTML to GitHub to be able to use plugins to do this.

Comment: Would this work for sorting by full file path?
i.e. `{% assign sorted_pages = site.pages | sort:"path" %}`
and `00-directory/00-file.md` would come before `01-anotherDir/00-anotherFile.md`

Comment: It does work! Thanks so much! I've been fighting with this for days.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. If you're on GitHub Pages, this is the answer you're looking for. Of course, I only have 5 nav items, so it's probably overkill to solve with code change. I have two variants of the same site, though. My OCD insisted that their link orders match. :P

Comment: Hi @Wojtek `sort:"weight"` just works for me, fyi. By the way thanks for the excellent solution.

Comment: Sorting by weight does work! [See answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19295612/2898712)
Maybe that was changed in Jekyll.

Answer (score 15):

I've written a simple Jekyll plugin to solve this issue:

1. Copy `sorted_for.rb` from https://gist.github.com/3765912 to `_plugins` subdirectory of your Jekyll project:

   ```
   module Jekyll
     class SortedForTag < Liquid::For
       def render(context)
         sorted_collection = context[@collection_name].dup
         sorted_collection.sort_by! { |i| i.to_liquid[@attributes['sort_by']] }

         sorted_collection_name = "#{@collection_name}_sorted".sub('.', '_')
         context[sorted_collection_name] = sorted_collection
         @collection_name = sorted_collection_name

         super
       end

       def end_tag
         'endsorted_for'
       end
     end
   end

   Liquid::Template.register_tag('sorted_for', Jekyll::SortedForTag)
   ```
2. Use tag `sorted_for` instead of `for` with `sort_by:property` parameter to sort by given property. You can also add `reversed` just like the original `for`.
3. Don't forget to use different end tag `endsorted_for`.

In your case the usage look like this:

```
<ul>
  {% sorted_for p in site.pages sort_by:weight %}
    <li>
      <a {% if p.url == page.url %}class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ p.url }}">
        {{ p.title }}
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endsorted_for %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Just a pity that you can't use custom plugins with GitHub pages… :-\

Comment: Nice, thanks for sharing. Just a little addition: in case not all of your items have the specified property, you can alter the `sort_by!` call to ignore those items: `sorted_collection.sort_by! { |i| i.to_liquid[@attributes['sort_by']] || 0 }` (replace 0 with infinity if you want it the other way around).

Answer (score 10):

The simplest solution would be to prefix the filename of your pages with an index like this:

00-home.html
01-services.html
02-page3.html

Pages are be ordered by filename. However, now you'll have ugly urls.

In your yaml front matter sections you can override the generated url by setting the permalink variable.

For instance:

```
---
layout: default
permalink: index.html
---
```

Comment: Nice one! Still a hack, but much simpler than the other answers.

Comment: Be careful with this if you push your site to github pages. For some reason the ordering will be messed up then. See also: https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap/issues/42#issuecomment-4982767

Answer (score 10):

Easy solution:

Assign a sorted array of `site.pages` first then run a for loop on the array.

Your code will look like:

```
{% assign links = site.pages | sort: 'weight' %}
{% for p in links %}
  <li>
    <a {% if p.url == page.url %}class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ p.url }}">
      {{ p.title }}
    </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This works in my navbar `_include` which is simply:

```
<section id="navbar">
    <nav>
        {% assign tabs = site.pages | sort: 'weight' %}
        {% for p in tabs %}
            <span class="navitem"><a href="{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a></span>
        {% endfor %}
    </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: Suddenly this started throwing errors on _post pages: `Liquid Exception: comparison of Hash with Hash failed in _posts/...`

Comment: This is the cleanest solution; there's just a slight error -- the sort key should be given as a string, i.e. sort: 'weight'. Updated the sample code.

Comment: The aforementioned issue is mentioned and resolved [here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/2299). It might take a while before the versions running GitHub pages are updated, though.

Answer (score 5):

I've solved this using a generator. The generator iterates over pages, getting the navigation data, sorting it and pushing it back to the site config. From there Liquid can retrieve the data and display it. It also takes care of hiding and showing items.

Consider this page fragment:

```
---
navigation:
  title: Page name
  weight: 100
  show: true
---
content.
```

The navigation is rendered with this Liquid fragment:

```
{% for p in site.navigation %}
<li> 
    <a  {% if p.url == page.url %}class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ p.url }}">{{ p.navigation.title }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Put the following code in a file in your _plugins folder:

```
module Jekyll

  class SiteNavigation < Jekyll::Generator
    safe true
    priority :lowest

    def generate(site)

        # First remove all invisible items (default: nil = show in nav)
        sorted = []
        site.pages.each do |page|
          sorted << page if page.data["navigation"]["show"] != false
        end

        # Then sort em according to weight
        sorted = sorted.sort{ |a,b| a.data["navigation"]["weight"] <=> b.data["navigation"]["weight"] } 

        # Debug info.
        puts "Sorted resulting navigation:  (use site.config['sorted_navigation']) "
        sorted.each do |p|
          puts p.inspect 
        end

        # Access this in Liquid using: site.navigation
        site.config["navigation"] = sorted
    end
  end
end
```

I've spent quite a while figuring this out since I'm quite new to Jekyll and Ruby, so it would be great if anyone can improve on this.

Answer (score 1):

I can get the code below works on with Jekyll/Liquid match to your requirement with category:

> - creates links to all existing pages,
> - sorted by weight (works as well on sorting per category),
> - highlight the current page.

On top of them it shows also number of post. All is done without any plug-in.

```
<ul class="topics">
{% capture tags %}
    {% for tag in site.categories %}
        {{ tag[0] }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign sortedtags = tags | split:' ' | sort %}
    {% for tag in sortedtags %}
    <li class="topic-header"><b>{{ tag }} ({{ site.categories[tag] | size }} topics)</b>
        <ul class='subnavlist'>
        {% assign posts = site.categories[tag] | sort:"weight" %}
        {% for post in posts %}
            <li class='recipe {% if post.url == page.url %}active{% endif %}'>
            <a href="/{{ site.github.project_title }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Check it on action on our *[networking page](http://hyip.github.io/world/net/)*. You may click a post to highlight the navigation, as well a given link to bring you to the source page where their weight is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to sort by weight and by tag and limit the number to 10, here's code to do it:

```
{% assign counter = '0' %}
{% assign pages = site.pages | sort: "weight"  %}
{% for page in pages %}
{% for tag in page.tags %}
{% if tag == "Getting Started" and counter < '9' %}
{% capture counter %}{{ counter | plus:'1' }}{% endcapture %}
<li><a href="{{ page.permalink | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{page.title}}</a></li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution above by @kikito also worked for me. I just added a few lines to remove pages without weight from the navigation and to get rid of white space:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    {% for weight in (1..5) %}
      {% unless p.weight %}
        {% for p in site.pages %}
          {% if p.weight == weight %}
            {% if p.url == page.url %}
              <li>{{ p.title }}</li>
            {% else %}
              <li><a href="{{ p.url }}" title="{{ p.title }}">{{ p.title }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @WingLeong I didn't do any tests but that's what worked out for me.