# Order posts by post yml front-matter number

Tags: jekyll

I have each post as a company in a building and I wanna order each post (company) by `suite` a number set in the yml front-matter of each post. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's another question that asked something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9053066/6884), just with "regular" pages instead of blog posts.

Adapting the accepted answer to your needs *(`suite` and posts, instead of `weight` and pages)*, you need to do the following:

#### Define a `suite` in the front-matter of each post:

```
---
layout: post
title: whatever
date: 2014/04/19 00:00
suite: 3
---
```

#### Display a list of all posts sorted by `suite`:

```
<ul>
{% for suite in (1..10) %}
    {% for post in site.posts %}
        {% if post.suite == suite %}
            <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```