# Navigation in Jekyll sorted by weight

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I want to make a navigation sorted by weight on my Jekyll site. I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/aucor/jekyll-plugins/blob/master/weighted_pages.rb), but I want to show in navigation only pages with weight, instead of showing pages without weight at the end of the list.

So I changed the plugin like this:

```
module Jekyll
  class WeightedPagesGenerator < Generator
    safe true
    def generate(site)
      site.pages.each do |page|
        if page.data["weight"] != nil

          site.config['weighted_pages'] = site.pages.sort_by { |a| 
            a.data['weight'] }

        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I get an error: Generating... /_plugins/sorted_navigation.rb:10:in `sort_by': comparison of NilClass with 2 failed (ArgumentError).

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: try this in your method, site.config['weighted_pages'] = site.pages.sort_by { |a| 
            a.data['weight'].to_i }

Comment: you can replace this block site.pages.each do |page|
        if page.data["weight"] != nil

          site.config['weighted_pages'] = site.pages.sort_by { |a| 
            a.data['weight'] }

        end
      end

Comment: with  site.config['weighted_pages'] = site.pages.sort_by { |a| a.data['weight'].to_i }

Comment: @AlokAnand, thank you very much. Now it actually doesn't give any error when I generate the site, but I still get pages without weight in my navigation. So I guess now the if statement doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Jekyll 2.2.0 you can sort an array of objects by any object property. Sorting by weight is now possible and far more efficient than older solutions (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25513956/1548376)

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much. Is there any way I can sort posts instead of pages by order?

Comment: `{% assign posts = site.posts | sort:"weight"  %}` or sort by name or whatever you want to put in the front matter.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using this plugin. Instead I use liquid tags from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9126294/3354729) and now my navigation looks like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    {% for weight in (1..5) %}
      {% unless p.weight %}
        {% for p in site.pages %}
          {% if p.weight == weight %}
            <li><a {% if p.url == page.url %}class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ p.url }}" title="{{ p.title }}">{{ p.title }}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```