# Jeykll: Sorting files in _data subfolders by common property

Tags: sorting, for-loop, jekyll, liquid

I want to iterate over each file in `_data/sections/`, but have output sorted by data contained in said files (order property). The current output happens to be in the correct order, though I am not sure why, and the order does *not* change when modifying the sorted property.

The files are structured as follows:

```
// project/_data/sections/food.yml

title: Food
order: 2
content: "Food ipsum dolor sit amet."

-----

// project/_data/sections/drink.yml

title: Drink
order: 1
content: "Drink ipsum dolor sit amet."
```

Following the structure found on the [Jekyll docs for data files](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/), the for-loop code is as follows:

```
// project/index.html

// ...
{% for section_hash in site.data.sections | sort: 'order' %}
  {% assign section = section_hash[1] %}
  <p><strong>{{ section.title }}</strong> - {{ section.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
// ...
```

I have also tried to sort the sections before passing them to the for-loop [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053066/sorted-navigation-menu-with-jekyll-and-liquid):

```
{% assign sections_sorted = sita.data.sections | sort: 'order' %}
{% for section in sections_sorted %}
  <p><strong>{{ section.title }}</strong> - {{ section.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Finally, I have tried to move the `order` property to the front-matter of each section file in `_data/sections/`, but that has resulted in the exception: `Liquid Exception: no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

```
// project/_data/sections/drink.yml
---
order: 1
---

title: Drink
content: "Drink ipsum dolor sit amet."
```

Is this possible with files in subdirectories of `_data/`? How can I sort the output of these files numerically by `order`, reverse-alphabetically by `title`, and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Just faced the same issue. `site.data.whatever`for folders is always Hash

```
{ file_name => file_content, ... }
```

Unfortunately Liquid arrays filters don't support hashes. To convert it to array the following filter can be used:

```
module Jekyll
  module ValuesFilter
    def values(input)
      case
        when input.instance_of?(Hash)
          input.values
        else
          input
      end
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::ValuesFilter)
```

Put it into `_plugins` folders and use the next Liquid code:

```
{% assign ordered_items =(site.data.folder_name | sort | order: 'field') %}
{% for item in ordered_items %}
    {{ item.<property_name> }}
{% endfor %}
```

This code also works if `folder_name` points to a CSV file or an array inside JSON file.

Comment: should be `folder_name | values | sort | order: 'field' ` in the final call?

Answer (score 1):

Your second example should work, but you have a typo: `sita.data.sections` should be `site.data.sections`.

```
{% assign sections_sorted = site.data.sections | sort: 'order' %}
{% for section in sections_sorted %}
  <p><strong>{{ section.title }}</strong> - {{ section.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether my problem is related to yours or not. I am trying to sort files in the `_data` directory, but my files are in a JSON format. No matter what I do, I receive this error message: `jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  no implicit conversion of String into Integer`. My JSON files do not contain any frontmatter at all. The error message tells me that Ruby tries to access an array by using a string, but expects an integer for any reason, e.g. `my_array["blah"]` instead of `my_array[1]`. This does not make much sense as `sort:"blah"` actually provides a string. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Concerning your first example:
`{% for section_hash in site.data.sections | sort: 'order' %}`
I don't think this works, I believe this is not implemented in Liquid. See this issue: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/pull/304

But I cannot see why your second example does not work, maybe I misunderstand something here:
`{% assign sections_sorted = sita.data.sections | sort: 'order' %}`
Apparently, this should work from Jekyll 2.2.0 onwards, see this thread: [Sorted navigation menu with Jekyll and Liquid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053066/sorted-navigation-menu-with-jekyll-and-liquid)

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is pretty dated, I've run into the same problem.
My solution was to provide a _index.xml which defined the order of e.g. projects.

We are in this folder: **_data/projects**

There are many files, e.g.

- _index.yml
- project_1.yml
- project_2.yml
- project_3.yml

The content of _index.yml looks like this:

```
- project_2
- project_1
- project_3
```

And the call to display your projects looks like this:

```
{% for project_id in site.data.projects["_index"] %}
{% assign project = site.data.projects[project_id] %} 
  // do something with the project
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this helps