# Jekyll/Liquid string comparisons make no sense

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In a simple Jekyll site, I have a menu looking like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li {% if page.url=='/' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li {% if page.url=='/page1.html' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
    <li {% if page.url=='/page2.html' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
    <li {% if page.url=='/page3.html' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I output `page.url` just before or after this block, it always contains the expected value, i.e. the path of the current page, say '/page2.html'. However, it's always the Home tab that receives the 'active' class, suggesting that *that* string comparison succeeded and that `page.url` is equal to '/'. The fact that visiting the Home page results in `page.url` containing '/index.html' and not '/' adds to the mystery.

I'm new to Jekyll and Liquid, but I can't think of a reason for this behavior. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems crazy, but it appears that the liquid engine requires spaces around the `==`. So this should work:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li {% if page.url == '/' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li {% if page.url == '/page1.html' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
    <li {% if page.url == '/page2.html' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
    <li {% if page.url == '/page3.html' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I still don't understand why the first `if` returns `true` but this should fix your immediate problem.

Comment: Crazy language! People must be struck by this problem every day. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Chalk me up as another victim of this!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
{% for p in site.pages %}
  <li{% if p.url == page.url %} class="active"{% endif %}>
    <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to order your pages in the menu you can have a look at 
[Sorted navigation menu with Jekyll and Liquid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053066/sorted-navigation-menu-with-jekyll-and-liquid)

Comment: Thanks David, that looks useful, but doesn't explain why my current approach doesn't work. Do you have any idea?